# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript

I have an html file using which I am rendering a react component.
Here is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../elements/css/elements.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico"/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Text Modal Demo</h1>
<p>Styled using the Elements SDK.</p>
<br/>
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.js?features=CustomEvent,Intl.~locale.en,Intl.~locale.fr"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jsfiles/textModal/dist.text-modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jsfiles/textModal/text-modal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my text-modal.js file

```
function init() {

  // Demo eventing API
  document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('o.InitTextModal', {
      detail: { elementId: 'app', contentTemplateLarge: true, footerVisible: true, successBtnCallback: () => { console.log('¡¡success button pressed!!') }}
  }
  ));
}
window.onload = init;
```

When I try to load the html file, I see this error in my console 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )  at Line 5 text-modal.js
which is this line - detail: `{ elementId: 'app', contentTemplateLarge: true, footerVisible: true, successBtnCallback: () => { console.log('¡¡success button pressed!!') }}`

This issue is seen only on IE 11 and Android device. Works fine for iOS

Comment: Does IE11 support arrow functions?

Comment: No. http://caniuse.com/#search=arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE11 [doesn't support](http://caniuse.com/#search=arrow) arrow functions. You need to rewrite your javascript:

Before:

```
 () => { console.log('¡¡success button pressed!!') }
```

After:

```
 function() { console.log('¡¡success button pressed!!') }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like arrow syntax is [not supported on IE 11 or some older versions of Android browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this much but as far as the error looks this thingy here seems it is not supported better use the same old way of creating functions to make sure it is compatible anywhere

```
successBtnCallback: () => { // Anything else }
```

hope that helps